# Managing pagination or cursor with deleting items in the list

Tags: orm, ajax, repository, pagination

I have a REST API that could GET, POST, PUT, DELETE models.

My problem is when I paginate that with ajax call combining with DELETE operations. My problem comes after few steps

- list one page
- list the following page (when i scoll down)
- I delete a row

**Problem**. when I ask for the 3rd page, i miss a row, because, asking for rows from 21 to 30, its bad, as the 20th will not be showed.  How can I manage such  listing that changes in data?

Comment: How are you asking for the next page?  `page=1`? or `start=42`?

Comment: My first solution would probably be to refresh (re-retrieve) the current page after the delete. That shows the user that the row really has been deleted and brings the (new) 20th row into view.

Comment: @MichaelT: by using page parameters; Bart: sound like a good idea. I should try it.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: one problem might appear: if I delete a row from 1st page, then after refreshing 1st page, the 10th row will be the same like the eleventh.

Comment: @user237329: Of course you should refresh all pages that are (partially) visible to the user and that might be affected by the deletion/insertion.